# Magento getData() is not returning a value

Tags: php, magento

I have an attribute `cdn_image_name` which works just fine for about 90 000 products. Recently the content editors reported that there are about three products that are missing images. I've pinpoint the issue to Magento's getData() method.

This is a similar code to the original one.

```
$cdnImageName = $product->getData('cdn_image_name');
```

I've also tried:

```
$cdnImageName = $product->getCdnImageName();
$cdnImageName = $product->getAttributeText('cdn_image_name');
```

In the Magento admin interface I see the field populated with the correct value. I've checked the DB it also has the value in place. It simply returns "null" with any of the ways above that I've tried.

Note: there is no typo issue, I've checked "n" times, it's working for almost all products but a few.

Comment: Hi , Have you tried getting attribute set ? $attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set");
$attributeSetModel->load($product->getAttributeSetId()); Can you check what this returns ?

Comment: Marian,i hope there are issue in attribute set.... This attribute is not assigning in attribute set

Comment: try to run index process

Comment: I did run the index process, Thanks Keyur

Comment: Do you have multiple storeviews? If so check values for this fields in all store views, maybe some of them overwrites the default one.

Comment: Pleas giveme system.log and exception.log file

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You could use a direct SQL query then fetch it in Magento:

```
// Create read and write connections to the database
    $resource  = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $connRead  = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

    // find out attribute id of cdn_image_name from the Magento database
    $attributeId = 123;

    $sqlCdnImageName = "SELECT `cpet`.`value`
            FROM `catalog_product_entity` `cpe`
            INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` `cpet`
            ON `cpe`.`entity_id` = `cpet`.`entity_id`
            WHERE `cpet`.`attribute_id` = $attributeId
            AND `cpe`.`entity_id` = " . $product->getId() . ";";

     $cdnImageName = $connRead->fetchOne($sqlCdnImageName);
```

Comment: Direct SQL queries for this type of problem are not at all advised.

Answer (score 3):

This problem can happen if you set 'used in product listing' to 'no'. Just change it in 'Manage Attribute'.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using custom attribute then you can use it like

```
$cdnImageName = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($product_new->getData("entity_id"), "cdn_image_name", $storeID);


$product_new->getData("entity_id") = your product id
```

**EDIT**

Also check

```
$_item = $this->getProduct()->getId();
$_resource = $this->getProduct()->getResource();
$optionValue = $_resource->getAttributeRawValue($_item, 'cdn_image_name', Mage::app()->getStore());
echo $optionvalue;
```

hope this will work for you.

Comment: The first piece of code works same as mine does, it returns proper value for thr products that my code does, and false for those products in question. The second one doesn't work. At the moment nothing changed, I'm still in the same place. Thanks

Comment: I found your answer while looking into a different scenario.  My UPC attribute was not being returned for any products.  Your `getResourceModel()` approach worked for me in this case--thanks!

Comment: HOw do you know when to use getAttributeRawValue or getData()?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$cdnImageName = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(), 'cdn_image_name');
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry mate, I still get a "false" value.